# Sending objects using sockets - JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, sockets, stream

So I am creating an application using sockets. And I have the client who sends a message and it passes to the server using `writeObject(new String("Name|Message"));`.

And I read the message in the server using `readObject();`

I am trying to pass this string object to an array. But I get `[Ljava.lang.String;@6bb9ae1a`.

Here is what I am trying:

```
ObjectInputStream saida = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
String[] read = saida.readObject().toString().split("|");
System.out.println(read);
```

I tried also to make variables for each split:

```
   String readm = read[1];
   String readn = read[0];
```

But it returns me "" as the name and "A" as the message (?)

Ow, and the socket is working, because if I do `(String) saida.readObject();` it returns me the normal string.

Comment: Have looked up the Contract of ''String''s ''toString'' Method?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work, as I said it returns [Ljava.lang.String;@6bb9ae1a.

Comment: Sorry. Gabriel is right ... thought into wrong direction.

Comment: `[Ljava.lang.String;@6bb9ae1a` is the output of an array of strings, not of a string. You have to print each string in the array individually.

Comment: Gabriel, read the question and the correct answer, before making any post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use like that :

```
saida.readObject().toString().split("\\|");
```

and then

```
String readm = read[1];
String readn = read[0];
```

Because pipe symbol is the special character and splitting special chars is different. And you cannot use systemoutprintln to print the string array.